# Post file directly to Box - no OAuth

Tags: file, https, upload, box-api, box

Good day -

Our enterprise uses Box for cloud storage.  There are many intranet web applications behind our firewall *that do not use HTTPS*.

When a user uses one of these web applications, it's easy for the app to **retrieve** files for processing: we just use the Box Picker and the user performs the authorization, which then sends the file token to our app.  Then we retrieve the file securely from Box to our server.

But what if our application generates a file for the user, and we want to give the user a quick way to **upload** it to Box?  Today, we would have to use OAuth, which generates a callback that has to be to HTTPS.  That's not a workable solution because we don't have SSL on some intranet servers.

Is there a way to let the user "POST" this file directly to Box from the browser?

For example:

```
<form method="POST" action="**https://www.box.com**...." type="multipart..">
    <input type="hidden name="fileContent" value="base64 encoded file content"></input>\
    <input type="hidden name="fileNname" value="...."></input>
</form>
```

This way, our server "passes off" the file to Box, which then performs authentication as needed, and proceeds with putting it in the user's account.  It would not require a secure callback to our server at all.  Of course, this POST is via HTTPS to Box.

Is there any way to do this without needing OAuth?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your intention to upload the file to that particular user's Box?

Comment: Yes, the intention is to allow the user to upload it to his/her own Box account.  We'd post it, Box authenticates the user, then continues with letting the user select the folder or whatever.

Comment: I don't know that this is possible. Could you perhaps ask to run this app on one of the servers that does support SSL?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not feasible for us in the near term.